# How can I utilize Salesforce as a remote auth using third party scripting?

Tags: javascript, rest-api, static-resources

I have implemented a knowledge base from a third party tool and I would like to use Salesforce as a remote auth idp for the application. They have provided some options for scripts, namely PHP, Javascript, and vb.net. Their [documentation](https://support.knowledgeowl.com/help/remote-authentication#create-your-remote-auth-token-request-and-script) is pretty thorough in terms of the scripts, and essentially the process is to make an API call, passing through the username from Salesforce, get a token in return, and inject that into the URL to authenticate.

Our users would be accessing this from an experience site, via a link.

The following is their javascript code format:

```
//only need this if you do not already have jquery loaded
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
 /**
 * This example assumes that you have already authenticated
 * the end user in your system
 */

 /* if a non logged in user attempts to go directly to an article,
 our system will redirect them back to your landing page with the
 URL variable "r" that equals the original request URI. After
 authentication in your system, use this variable to send them
 to the originally requested page. */
 //grab the value of r
 var redirect = "/help"; //default homepage
 var pageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
 var urlVariables = pageURL.split('?');
 for (var i = 0; i < urlVariables.length; i++) 
 {
 var parameterName = urlVariables[i].split('=');
 if (parameterName[0] == 'r') 
 {
 redirect = parameterName[1];
 }
 }
 
 //static vars
 var token;
 var kbEndpoint = "https://{YOUR KNOWLEDGEOWL KB URL}/help/remote-auth"; //where we will be sending them back -- eg https://yoursite.knowledgeowl.com/help/remote-auth
 var callURL    = "https://app.knowledgeowl.com/api/head/remotelogin.jsonp"; //knowledgeowl auth endpoint
 var data       = {
 _authbykey: '{API KEY}', //KnowledgeOwl API key
 project : '{KB ID}' //knowledge base ID
 }

 //request the token and redirect to desired page
 $.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: callURL,
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 data: data
 }).success(function(data) {
 //check for valid response
 if(data && data.valid === true) {
 //grab the token
 token = data.data[0].token;
 
 kbEndpoint += "?n=" + token;
 kbEndpoint += "&r=" + redirect;
 
 //optional reader object creation / assertion
 kbEndpoint += "&reader[ssoid]=" + {READER UNIQUE ID}; //optional, if no ssoid is passed username will be used
 kbEndpoint += "&reader[username]=" + {READER NAME OR EMAIL}; //required
 kbEndpoint += "&reader[icon]=" + {READER PICTURE}; //optional
 kbEndpoint += "&reader[first_name]=" + {READER FIRST NAME}; //optional
 kbEndpoint += "&reader[last_name]=" + {READER LAST NAME}; //optional
 kbEndpoint += "&reader[groups]=" + {KNOWLEDGEOWL GROUP NAMES}; //optional, comma seperated list
 kbEndpoint += "&reader[custom1]=" + {STRING}; //optional
 kbEndpoint += "&reader[custom2]=" + {STRING}; //optional
 kbEndpoint += "&reader[custom3]=" + {STRING}; //optional
 kbEndpoint += "&reader[custom4]=" + {STRING}; //optional
 kbEndpoint += "&reader[custom5]=" + {STRING}; //optional

 //redirect user back with the aquired token and initial page request URI
 window.location.replace(kbEndpoint);
 } else {
 //handle empty return error
 }
 }).error(function(data){
 //handle ajax errors
 });
</script>
```

My general understanding of how to do this through the javascript that they provided is as follows:

- Store the 'script src=' portion as a static resource, and call it as such
- Execute the code within a lightning component

The details that I'm not so clear on are these:

- How do I pass the salesforce username within this script? They provide this for the API call  `kbEndpoint += "&reader[username]=" + {READER NAME OR EMAIL}; //required`, so what format would I utilize within those brackets for the username?
- How do I make this something that runs after the link within our experience site is clicked? As in, what URL am I pointing the link to? Is a lightning component the correct tool for this?

I considered using the PHP script with the Salesforce PHP SDK, but it looks like that's only for Marketing cloud and this would fall under Service cloud.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, particularly if it can be light on the jargon. I am not very familiar with Salesforce's developer side of things and the intricacies of those systems.